# SQL rows for times between 2 timestamps

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with records containing 2 timestamps each associating with a block of time an agent is supposed to be doing a task like below.

```
ID  AgentName  Date     Task        Start           End
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 12:30   3/12/18 14:15
2   Doris   3/12/2018   Break       3/12/18 14:15   3/12/18 14:30
3   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 14:30   3/12/18 16:45
4   Doris   3/12/2018   Lunch       3/12/18 16:45   3/12/18 17:15
5   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 17:15   3/12/18 19:00
6   Doris   3/12/2018   Break       3/12/18 19:00   3/12/18 19:15
7   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 19:15   3/12/18 21:00
```

I need to break out each of those records into 15 min interval time slots like so...

```
ID  AgentName   Date    Task        Start           End             Interval
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 12:30   3/12/18 14:15   12:30
1   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 12:30   3/12/18 14:15   12:45
1   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 12:30   3/12/18 14:15   13:00
1   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 12:30   3/12/18 14:15   13:15
1   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 12:30   3/12/18 14:15   13:30
1   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 12:30   3/12/18 14:15   13:45
1   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 12:30   3/12/18 14:15   14:00
2   Doris   3/12/2018   Break       3/12/18 14:15   3/12/18 14:30   14:15
3   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 14:30   3/12/18 16:45   14:30
3   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 14:30   3/12/18 16:45   14:45
3   Doris   3/12/2018   Available   3/12/18 14:30   3/12/18 16:45   15:00
```

I've got a reference table with the 15 min intervals but I'm at a loss as to where to go now.  I've tried this and can't get the extra intervals to return.

```
select * 
from dbo.Tbl_timeSlot t 
full outer join dbo.Schedule s on t.Slot = convert(time, s.Start)
where convert(date, Start) = '3/12/18'
  and AgentName = 'Doris'
```

Comment: I recommend you to format your data in a readable way (either via a picture or a better tabular way). I really doubt anybody can understand your data clearly

Comment: Have a look at this to see if it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197442/sql-server-2000-breaking-a-query-up-into-15-minute-blocks

Comment: @E.Garcia you can check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution using CTE and live demo here http://rextester.com/live/UVG28279

```
declare @myclock table (ID int, AgentName varchar(100), LogDate Date, Task varchar(20),StartTime DateTime,EndTime DateTime)


insert into @myclock
values 
(1   ,'Doris','3/12/2018','Available','3/12/18 12:30','3/12/18 14:15'),
(2   ,'Doris','3/12/2018','Break','3/12/18 14:15','3/12/18 14:30'),
(3   ,'Doris','3/12/2018','Available','3/12/18 14:30','3/12/18 16:45'),
(4   ,'Doris','3/12/2018','Lunch','3/12/18 16:45','3/12/18 17:15'),
(5   ,'Doris','3/12/2018','Available','3/12/18 17:15','3/12/18 19:00'),
(6   ,'Doris','3/12/2018','Break','3/12/18 19:00','3/12/18 19:15'),
(7   ,'Doris','3/12/2018','Available','3/12/18 19:15','3/12/18 21:00')

--select * from @myclock;

;with myCteNewClock as (
  select *,StartTime NewStartTime from @myclock
  union all
  select x.ID,x.AgentName,x.LogDate,x.Task,x.StartTime,x.EndTime, dateadd(minute,15,x.NewStartTime) NewStartTime from myCteNewClock x
     inner join @myclock c 
       on x.ID = c.ID  
     where
        dateadd(minute,15,x.NewStartTime) <= x.EndTime 

 )
select ID,AgentName,LogDate,Task,StartTime,EndTime, convert(time(0),NewStartTime) [Interval]
 from myCteNewClock order by ID
```

Comment: Thanks maSTAShuFu thats exactly what I needed!